# Download image using url and save to internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I have tried different methods. But still I am not able to save the image to the specified location. I don't know what's the problem. need some suggestions. The path is not created and the image in not saved.

```
class DownloadAndSaveImage(context: Context) : AsyncTask<String, Unit, Unit>() {


    private var mContext: WeakReference<Context> = WeakReference(context)
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?) {
        val url = params[0]
        val requestOptions = RequestOptions().override(100)
            .downsample(DownsampleStrategy.CENTER_INSIDE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)

        mContext.get()?.let {
            val bitmap = Glide.with(it)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .submit()
                .get()

            try {
                val path = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                val dir =path.absolutePath
                val file=File(dir+"/EAcademy","schoolImage.jpg")
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdir()
                }
                val out = FileOutputStream(file)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out)
                out.flush()
                out.close()
                Log.i("Tribhuwan", "Saved Image")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.i("Tribhuwan", "Failed to save")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you will have to write the file writing part inside a glide image loaded listener

Comment: Could you please show me an example ??

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdir()
                }`. That should be: `if (!file.exists())if ( !
                    file.mkdir()){Toast(could not make directory); return;
                }`.

Comment: if you want i will give you code but that it is in java language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using file.mkdir() so it will create schoolImage.jpg directory and not file. You can do it like this

```
val path = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
            val dir =path.absolutePath
            val folder=File(dir+"/EAcademy")

            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdirs()
            }
            val file = File(folder, "schoolImage.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanx bro. I already solved the problem. And is similar to yours. i was doing that mistake.